# should I update cache with redis every times when one of them changing

Tags: mysql, redis

Let's look at the following scenario:
A website has 10000 player, to make question easier, I use mysql  storage player with just one table: "player_table"
------table here-----
name string
score int

now, I want to show Top 100 of those players  by socre.
if only with mysql, I have to caculate Top 100 every time, so I choice Redis to storage Top 100 with sorted set data type.

But if one of those players' score chaning, what should I do, update Top 100 every time??

Thanks for you advance

Comment: The easiest thing is just to store all the players and their scores in the sorted set. Then it's trivial to update the score and get the top 100. If you really only want to store the top 100 in Redis, then you'll have to update the score in the DB, compare it to the lowest score in the top 100, and then potentially change players in the Redis dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce an id field in your database first, it doesn't seem right to have name as the primary key ( if it is a unique username of the player, then it is fine).

1.Keep a sorted set of all players, with their game score as the score field in the sorted set.

2. Whenever a game is finished, update your mysql table, and do ZINCRBY operation on your redis sorted set for the players.
3. Whenever you need a leaderboard, do [ZREVRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrange) operation to get top players sorted by their score.

Comment: If my leaderboard need every player head-image, should I zrevrange to get top 100 first, and then use id with Mysql to get it's head-image?? Or is there other way ???

Comment: @helpme123 yes, that would be a good way. It would be a primary key based IN query, so would be performant.